# AttributeError at /accounts/Login_with_OTP/ 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django-views, python-3.8

I am trying to fetch details from the Django User model. But I got an error like 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'.I don't know how to solve this error. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
def otp_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    phones = request.POST['phone']
    print(phones)
    details = get_user_model.objects.get(phone=phones)
    print(details)
    if details is None:
        return render(request, "otp_login.html", {'msg': "No user registered with this mobile number."})
    request.session['phone']=phones
    return redirect('otp')
return render(request, "otp_login.html")
```

urls.py

```
path('Login_with_OTP/', views.otp_login,name="otp_login"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
details = get_user_model.objects.get(phone=phones)
```

with

```
 User = get_user_model()
 details = User.objects.get(phone=phones)
```